# Mapping by index using streams

Tags: java, java-8

The following is working but is there a way to do it using Java 8 streams? Hurdled by trying to use index.

```
private static final StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
private void setAllArgumentValues(String[] parameterNames, Object[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < parameterNames.length; i++) {
        context.setVariable(parameterNames[i], args[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, but the code would be less readable. Just because streams exist doesn't mean that for loops shouldn't be used anymore. The code would be safer, and easier to use with streams, if instead of having two parallel arrays (potentially not of the same length), you had a single array, or better, a single list, of objects. Each object would have a parameterName and an arg.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You could use an [`IntStream.range(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) like

```
IntStream.range(0, parameterNames.length)
        .forEach(i -> context.setVariable(parameterNames[i], args[i]));
```